# In JMeter logs are not displayed in Log viewer

Tags: jmeter

Whenever I ran  the test logs are not displayed in log viewer panel  in application, logs are displayed in command prompt.

- Can anyone pls suggest for this issue?
- How can I see logs in log viewer panel instead of cmd prompt?

I was enabled logviewer check box also.

Answer (score 0):

You may add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and write this code in Groovy:

```
println("Test message");
```

In that case you will see message in cmd console window.

If you want to print your message to JMeter Log Viewer use this code instead:

```
log.info("Test message:" + vars.get("yourVariableName"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your [JMeter Logging Configuration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) is corrupt, either try re-installing JMeter by [downloading](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) a "fresh" version or replace *log4j2.xml* file contents with the one from [JMeter source repository](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_0/bin/log4j2.xml)